# page doesn't display anything

Tags: javascript, html

so I wrote a script to display 5 random arrays, but the page doesn't display anything.
here's the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function start(){
        var arr(5),result;
        result=document.getElementById("arraying");
        result="<p>";
        for(var i=0; i<5;i++){
          arr[i]=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
          result+="arr["+i+"]= "+arr[i]+"</p><p>";
        }
        result+="</p>";
      }
      window.addEventListener("load",start,false);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="arraying"></div>
  </body>  
</html>
```

I tried removing `result=document.getElementById` and write `document.getElementById.innerHTML=result` in the end of the function but didn't work. what's the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the same variable for different purposes at the same time. First you assign a DOM element to `result`, and immediately on the next line you overwrite `result` with a `string`.

Build a string `htmlStr` inside your loop, and when that is done, assign this string to `result.innerHTML` property:

```js
function start() {
  let arr = [],
    result, htmlStr = '';
  result = document.getElementById("arraying");
  htmlStr += "<p>";
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arr[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    htmlStr += "arr[" + i + "]= " + arr[i] + "</p><p>";
  }
  htmlStr += "</p>";
  result.innerHTML = htmlStr;
}
window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
```

```html
<div id="arraying"></div>
```

Comment: Important to note: Do pre-build the HTML in a variable instead of using `innerHTML` directly, as shown in this answer. Because the content of `innerHTML` is validated immediately after assignment, any unclosed elements will be closed, which in this case would lead to a lot of empty `p` elements with text nodes inbetween. Also, assignments to `innerHTML` may cause reflow.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you seem to be missing some basic javascript concepts.

### array size

This is probably your main issue:

```js
var arr(5)
```

This does not make sense in javascript. Array length does not need to be predefined since all arrays are of dynamic length. Simply define an array like this:

```js
var arr = []
```

Then later when you want to append new elements use `push` like this:

```js
arr.push( Math.floor(Math.random()*10) )
```

### adding html using `innerHTML`

There are different ways to dynamically inject html into your page. (It looks like) you tried to append the html as a string to the parent element. This is not possible.

You said you tried using `innerHTML`. That should work if used correctly.

A working implementation would work like this:

```js
function start() {
 var arr = []
 var result = "<p>"
 for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  arr.push( Math.floor(Math.random()*10) ) // Btw this array isn't actually needed.
  result += "arr[" + i + "] = " + arr[i] + "</p><p>"
 }
 document.getElementById("arraying").innerHTML = result
}
window.addEventListener("load", start, {passive: true});
```

### adding html using `createElement`

A generally better way of dynamically adding html elements is via `createElement`.

This way you dont have to write html and are therefore less prone for making errors. It is also more performant and easier to integrate into javascript.

I think the best explaination is a commented implementation:

```js
function start() {
 var myDiv = document.getElementById("arraying") // get parent node
 var arr = []
 for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  arr.push( Math.floor(Math.random()*10) )
  var p = document.createElement("p") // create p element
  p.innerText = "arr[" + i + "] = " + arr[i] // add text content to p element
  myDiv.append(p) // append p element to parent element
 }
}
window.addEventListener("load", start, {passive: true});
```

### small tips

The `let` keyword works mostly the same as the `var` keyword, but is generally preferred because of some edge cases in which `let` is superior.

Fusing strings and variables using the plus operator is generally considered bad practice. A better way to do the string concatenation would have been

```js
result += `arr[${i}] = ${arr[i]}</p><p>`
```